# AngularJS: find closest value in multiple-values object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, distribution

I am trying to learn some AngularJS creating a "simple" math tool that calculates a distribution.

I have an array of numbers and I managed to get the list of unique values with number of occurrences and percentage in an object (the unique number as the key, occurrences, percentage and the progressive percentage as the values). Example:

```
$scope.values = {"17" : [1, 0.02, 0.02],"18" : [6, 0.12, 0.14],"19" : [7, 0.14, 0.28],"20" : [9, 0.18, 0.46],"21" : [13, 0.26, 0.72], "22" : [4, 0.08, 0.8],"23" : [5, 0.1, 0.9],"24" : [1, 0.02, 0.92],"25" : [3, 0.06, 0.98],"26" : [1, 0.02, 1]}
```

The unique number is the key while the 3 values are respectively the number of occurrences, the percentage on the overall iterations and the progressive percentage. Example, the number 25 occurred 3 times, i.e. 6% of the times, and includes 98% of the occurrences of numbers smaller or equal to 25.

**Problem**
Given a "progressive percentage" I need to get the key of the nearest value to that percentage. So, the search must be performed only on the 3rd values (if that changes anything), should identify the closest value (select the greater of two equidistant values), should return the **key**.

In the example above:

- if I search for 0.75, I should get 21,
- if I search for 0.91, I should get 23.

Any help with this?

This is where I got so far:

```
function nearest(num, ar) {
        var i = 0,
            closest, closestDiff, currentDiff;
        for (i; i < ar.length; i++) {
            if (closest) {
                closestDiff = Math.abs(num - closest);
                currentDiff = Math.abs(num - ar[i]);
                if (currentDiff < closestDiff) {
                    closest = ar[i];
                }
                closestDiff = null;
                currentDiff = null;
            } else if (!closest) {
                //give initial value
                closest = ar[i];
            }
        }
function (pct) {
    $scope.milestones = [];
    var ms = $scope.getClosestNum(pct, $scope.values);
    $scope.milestones.push(ms);
    return $scope.milestones;
  };
```

But `{{getMilestones(0.75)}}` in my HTML doesn't return anything.

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far?

Comment: Where's the code you are using to filter the array? The idea here isn't for us to write your code from scratch, but to help you resolve your code issues. Also need to clarify what the sorting parameters are

Comment: @charlietfl you are right and I am sorry. I added the specific piece of code to the question. I also put the whole code in JSFiddle but it is not working at all (while it is working locally on my computer): http://jsfiddle.net/nitecorp/edhy6927/

Comment: I now added both my function and the filter suggested by pankajparkar in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nitecorp/edhy6927/13/
My function is always returning the first element of the array... I am not sure it is actually looking specifically amongst the 3rd values.

Comment: @MirkoG.  why your array values contains in `"17 : [1, 0.02, 0.02]"` double quotes, any reason?

Comment: No specific reason... I am pushing the values into the array with this function: `$scope.getDistribution` (http://jsfiddle.net/nitecorp/edhy6927/16/)

Comment: @pankajparkar I understand now what you mean. Because of the double quotes that is interpreted as a unique value in the array...

Comment: @MirkoG. correct it should be array or json to process it inside `forEach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have found the solution myself. Thanks to @pankajparkar I understood that I was not saving values in a proper array. Starting from that I thought that an object would have been much more appropriate. So, gathered the numbers in a more "clean" object like:

```
{"34":0.04,"35":0.1,"36":0.12,"37":0.14,"38":0.16,"39":0.18,"40":0.22,"41":0.28,"43":0.36,"44":0.38,"45":0.42,"46":0.48,"47":0.52,"48":0.6,"49":0.64,"50":0.7,"51":0.8,"52":0.88,"53":0.92,"54":0.94,"55":1}
```

I am getting the closest value with a function that identify the two numbers that are immediately lower and higher than the value I am looking for, and then pick the closest one:

```
function findNearest(obj, value) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (value > obj[i]) prev = obj[i];
        else if (value <= obj[i]) {
            next = nums[i];
            percentage = (Math.abs(value - prev) < Math.abs(next - value)) ? prev : next;
            nearest = parseInt(Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {return obj[key] === percentage})[0]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return nearest;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
    var ms = getClosestNum(0.75,$scope.values);
```

should be

```
    var ms = $scope.getClosestNum(0.75,$scope.values);
```

You've defined the function on your $scope object (as is typical), so it should be called on that.

Comment: Well spotted thank! Yet the code is not working... :(

Answer (score 0):

You have `arr` as a parameter to your getClosest function, but you reference `ar` in the code. Seem to work when I correct this (as well as set ng-app="mcApp" in the html).

http://jsfiddle.net/edhy6927/9/

Comment: Hi Kjell, it is showing something but instead of returning the key with the closest 3rd value to 0.75, it´s always returning the whole first element of the array.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create a filter would be look something like below.

**Code**

```
app.filter('calculateThirdPercentile', function() {
    return function(values) {
        var returnValue = {};
        if (angular.isArray(values) && values.length > 0) {
            angular.forEach(values, function(value, index) {
               returnValue[(Math.ceil(value[2]*10)*10)+"%"] = index;
            });
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
results | calculateThirdPercentile
```

**Controller**

```
$filter('calculateThirdPercentile')($scope.results);
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: why on earth do you need `eval()`? Should never be used.

Comment: @charlietfl for dynamically assigning key like `50%` we need to, what would be an alternative?

Comment: create an object and use `[]` notation to assign property from variable. `var obj ={}; obj[value[3]] = index + "%"`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, I made changes :) does it looks good now?

Comment: @charlietfl now you could remove the downvote..i corrected my answer as you suggested..Thanks

Comment: not my downvote , BTW...you create an array but as soon as you give it a non-numeric index, it's not an array anymore in javascript. Might as well declare it as object from the start

Comment: Thats why at the start i was making one json string and then i was using eval() to convert json string to json ensure it would be json..

Comment: simply a matter of changing to `var returnValue = {};` to represent what it really will end up being

Comment: @pankajparkar I added your option to the JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/nitecorp/edhy6927/13/) but I am sure I did something wrong as the result is always empty. Compared to your suggestion I added a missing quote in the controller before calculateThirdPercentile and used $scope.values - which actually containing the list.

Comment: @MirkoG. i don't see anything in `results`

Comment: @pankajparkar I am not sure I understand what you mean. In $scope.values is stored the list containing the number as the key and 3 values. Should I add something else to the code?